# How to change the background color of a status bar gripper in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a status bar with a blue background at the bottom of a resizable dialog window. The status bar is set to show a resize gripper image that has a transparent background. The problem that I am having is that the background color that shows through matches the dialog background and I would like it to match the background color of the status bar.

I have found very little documentation on using a gripper or drawing a custom gripper for a status bar. Is there an easy way to change the background color used under the status bar  gripper so that it matches the background color of the status bar?